# Tried to reset iPhone 4s but stuck on black screen with loading spinner

Tags: iphone, icloud, restore

My phone fell down the stairs and went completely black. A friend of mine who fixes iPhones took it apart and found that the LCD plug had popped out in the fall so he put it back together and it was working fine, except for some reason I lost *all* my photos. No photos in camera roll, Photo Stream, etc. I *have* backed up daily. In fact, my phone is set to back up every time its plugged in to the charger.

A representative for Apple told me to reset my content and data and restore from iCloud and my photos should be there. Well, I attempted to reset my phone last night at 10:30pm. It is now the next day at 1:38pm and my phone is still with a black screen with the circular icon spinning around like its "thinking".

I can't reboot by pressing the home and lock buttons because my home button is broken. Any suggestions?

Comment: Leave it on until the battery drains... try to restore again. Since this might take a while get that home button fixed by a third party service, it's like 10-20$

Comment: Unfortunately, basilmir's answer is your best bet. The only alternative to speed things up would be to have your friend cut the power supply by removing the battery, although I think it's probably safer to just wait